# Table of contents: hide numbering for subsubsections

Tags: table-of-contents, numbering

I'd like to know if there is any way to hide the numbering for subsubsections in the table of contents keeping numbering for sections and subsections. In the picture you can see how it currently looks like.

Thank you

[image: That's how it looks now, I'd like to hide numbering for subsubsections]

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! You could use `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}`.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Which document class are you using? Should the subsubsections be numbered in the text?

Comment: @Bobyandbob: No, `\setcounter{tocdepth}{2}` would make the `subsubsections` vanish from ToC -- as far as I understood, the titles of the subsubsections shall still appear in the ToC, but the numbers be removed (although this might be weird)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\@sect` code is relevant for all `\section` etc. like macros and there is `\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
\ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth...` checking for the value of `secnumdepth`. By replacing this `\c@secnumdepth` by another counter value it is possible to hide the numbering in the ToC.

I've introduced the counter `secnumtocdepth` for this.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}


\newcounter{secnumtocdepth}

\setcounter{secnumtocdepth}{2}

\makeatletter
\AtBeginDocument{%

\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
  \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
    \let\@svsec\@empty
  \else
    \refstepcounter{#1}%
    \protected@edef\@svsec{\@seccntformat{#1}\relax}%
  \fi
  \@tempskipa #5\relax
  \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
    \begingroup
      #6{%
        \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
          \interlinepenalty \@M #8\@@par}%
    \endgroup
    \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
    \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
      \ifnum #2>\c@secnumtocdepth \else
        \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
      \fi
      #7}%
  \else
    \def\@svsechd{%
      #6{\hskip #3\relax
      \@svsec #8}%
      \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
      \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
        \ifnum #2>\c@secnumtocdepth \else
          \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
        \fi
        #7}}%
  \fi
  \@xsect{#5}}


}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\leveltohide}{2}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents



\section{First section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}

\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\section{Second section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}

\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

With a standard class you could use package `tocbasic`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tocbasic}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}
\DeclareTOCStyleEntry[
  entrynumberformat=\gobble,
  numwidth=0pt
]{tocline}{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

This would also work with a KOMA-Script class, but then `tocbasic` is already loaded by the class.

---

With a **KOMA-Script** class you could also use `\RedeclareSectionCommand`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\newcommand\gobble[1]{}
\RedeclareSectionCommand[
  tocentrynumberformat=\gobble,
  tocnumwidth=0pt
]{subsubsection}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Or you could redefine `\addsubsubsectiontocentry`:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\renewcommand\addsubsubsectiontocentry[2]{%
  \addtocentrydefault{subsubsection}{}{#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{First section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\section{Second section}
\subsection{Foo subsection}
\subsubsection{Foo subsubsection}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]